# Custom react-admin drag & drop list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

It can't drag. What is wrong with it?

I'm using react-sortable-hoc with material-ui to custom react-admin list page with drag & drop sortable.

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-visvesvaraya-4k3gs 
Source code: https://github.com/tangbearrrr/poc-ra-sort-drag/tree/main

Comment: your data state is undefined

Comment: @NishargShah i have updated new code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-visvesvaraya-4k3gs

Comment: @RahatSarawasee did you find solve?

Comment: @DaniilLoban Nope

Comment: Can you show structure of datа of LanguageList props?

Comment: @DaniilLoban https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: I spent a lot of time researching, the conclusion is that the whole list behaves like one element when dragged, so the background is white, it's hard to fix.

Comment: Also there are errors in console

Comment: Find a solution, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As I checked you are getting `data` from the props and in `props` there is no data field exists, so the error is coming from there

Here is the all props list

[image]

Comment: i have updated new code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-visvesvaraya-4k3gs

Answer (score 0):

The sortable method you are using is from [react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc), which adds huge complexity to react-admin.

Not so fast, I have run out of attempts trying to debug your code and come up with another solution works just fine but not so ideal, is to use `sortablejs`:

```
yarn add sortablejs
yarn add @types/sortablejs --dev
```

> Do not mess up with `react-sortablejs`, this also applies the same complexity level as `react-sortable-hoc`.

Let's use your [cmsLanguage](https://github.com/tangbearrrr/poc-ra-sort-drag/blob/main/src/cms_language/languageList.js) as an example, with changes to use `Datagrid` instead.

Just be reminded that this working solution needs several retries on null `el` (e.g. your data is fetching, slow network speed, etc). The code below has 3 retries, 1500 milliseconds per each retry. The initialisation will stop after 3 attempts.

```
import {Datagrid, ShowButton, TextField} from "react-admin";
import * as React from "react";
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import {useEffect} from "react";
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';

const LanguageList = () => {

    // This will run the effect after every render
    useEffect(() => {
        // https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable
        const retries = 3;
        const millisecords = 1500;
        let attempts = 0;

        const retrySortable = () => {
            const el = document.querySelector('#sortable-list tbody');
            if (!el) {
                if (++attempts >= retries) {
                    console.log(`cannot initialise sortable after ${retries} retries.`);
                } else {
                    setTimeout(() => retrySortable(), millisecords);
                }
            } else {
                // @ts-ignore
                new Sortable(el, {
                    handle: ".handle",
                    draggable: "tr",
                    animation: 150,  // ms, animation speed moving items when sorting, `0` — without animation
                    easing: "cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)", // Easing for animation. Defaults to null. See https://easings.net/ for examples.
                    // Element dragging ended
                    onEnd: (evt) => {
                        // @ts-ignore
                        const reorderedList: string[] = [];
                        const list = document.querySelectorAll('#sortable-list tbody td.column-name span');

                        [].forEach.call(list, function (span: Element) {
                            reorderedList.push(span.innerHTML);
                        });
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(reorderedList));
                        console.log(evt);
                    },
                });
            }
        }
        retrySortable();

    }, []);

    return (
        <section id="sortable-list">
            <Datagrid>
                <MenuIcon sx={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="handle"/>
                <TextField source="name"/>
                <ShowButton/>
            </Datagrid>
        </section>
    );
};

export default LanguageList;
```

When someone has a request for a demo, I will draw some time to make this a GitHub repo for better reference.